# Error while installing openjdk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, java

Got the below error while executing below command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dafault-jar
```

What is the problem? 
How can I fix t?

Comment: how do you know that the problem is with downloading?

Comment: `dafault-jar`? I assume you mean `default-jre`. There are a couple of problems with this, but they seem rather old and related to specific settings ([2012](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linaro-ci/+bug/962014), [2016](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24415)). You'll have to describe your case as accurately as possible: distro, version, architecture, repo mirror used, and are you on a pc, server, in the cloud, in Docker, etc.? See this for Ubuntu: [openjdk-8-jdk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-8-jdk) and [default-jre](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=default-jre))